# Export to Excel button from web page gives an error after the file is downloaded to the users machine: "File format or file extension is not valid"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Here's the Export button:

```
protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataTable = (DataTable) Session["finalSchedulesTable"];

            var dummyGv = new GridView {AllowPaging = false, DataSource = dataTable};
            dummyGv.DataBind();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Schedules " + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "_") + ".xlsx");
            Response.Charset = "";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            for (int i = 0; i < dummyGv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Apply text style to each Row
                dummyGv.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
            }

            dummyGv.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            const string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
```

If I change the file extension to ".xls" in the code above, the process works, however, I still get the following message when I try to open the file:

"The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xls' is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

If I say "yes", it'll open the file normally.

The issue here is that I don't want this message to pop-up. How do I go about fixing this?

All I'm trying to do is export the data to Excel and allow the user to open the file normally (without any warning messages).

Comment: Your `Response.ContentType` is that of XLSX. XLS is different.

Comment: what version of excel you are using to open the file?

Comment: I tried both of these and I get the same issue: Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

Comment: You're doing way too much crap in this method. All you should have here is Response.AddHeader and then serve the file content. No `style` or any other bs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method I've used in the past utilizes the EPPlus library:  http://epplus.codeplex.com/

So include that in your project, then you can call this method, just pass in your DataTable:

```
public static void DumpExcel(DataTable dataTable)
{
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("DataTable");

        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

        for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Column(i).AutoFit();

            if (dataTable.Columns[i - 1].DataType == System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
            {
                worksheet.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=table.xlsx");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

And you can easily add styling as well, for example if you wanted the header row to be bold:

```
worksheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

I use this often and do not receive an error like you were describing

Comment: by the way, im trying to BOLD it but the ".Style" cannot be resolved. do u know why?

Comment: No problem, and are you applying the style within the `using` statement above?